# React Google Maps Street View Panorama onCloseclick not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps-api

I'm using the StreetViewPanorama from react-google-maps/api. It comes with an onCloseclick prop that accepts a callback that supposedly fires when the close button is clicked. However, it is not firing whatever I do. Any advice?

```
<GoogleMap
      zoom={15}
      center={data.position}
      mapContainerClassName="map-container"
    >
      <StreetViewPanorama
        options={{
          position: data.position,
          visible: true,
        }}
        onCloseclick={(e) => {
          console.log(e); // this is not console logging anything
        }}
      />
    </GoogleMap>
```